# Making shortcuts cross desktop environment, possible?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, macro

I'm a big fan of keyboards, so a lot of thing a done by combination of keys, like open a file browser, web browser etc.

Is there some daemon that can monitor my key presses, and launch some program afterwards, so that I won't have to configure anything else after moving to another desktop environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you want to make a key combination perform an action, you can use [XBindKeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html). The companion program [xbindkeys_config](http://packages.debian.org/xbindkeys-config) can help define bindings. If you want to act on existing windows, invoke a program such as [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) or [wmctrl](http://sweb.cz/tripie/utils/wmctrl/).

If you want to make a key combination simulate a sequence of key presses, try [xmacro](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

This might not be quite what you're looking for, but if you install [dmenu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dmenu) and associate it to a key (so that's only one shortcut you'd need to define in any desktop manager), then you can use it to launch other programs.

`dmenu` presents itself as a small horizontal bar appearing on top of the screen, that will suggest completions of executables as you start typing them. For example, to launch `firefox` you's first press whatever key combination you mapped to dmenu (e.g. <kbd>Logo-R</kbd>) and then <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to diyism myboard python version: https://code.google.com/p/diyism-myboard/downloads/detail?name=myboard.py
The issue in it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270420/does-anyone-know-an-xlib-function-to-trap-a-keypress-event-without-losing-the-or/15404395#15404395